# (Weblogic) WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: exception, weblogic

I get this error when deploy in WebLogic.How do I solve this problem ?

**Exception :**
Deployment failed. The message was: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NullPointerException
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:130)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:212)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

**weblogic.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <jsp-descriptor>
    <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
    <debug>true</debug>
  </jsp-descriptor>
  <context-root>/TestProject</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

**sun-jaxws.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
    <endpoint  name="EftGidenServices" implementation="com.yaz.yazproject.eft.services.EftGidenServices"   url-pattern="/EftGidenServices"/>
    <endpoint  name="EhacizServices" implementation="com.yaz.yazproject.ehaciz.services.EhacizServices" url-pattern="/EhacizServices"/>
    <endpoint  name="CekService" implementation="com.yaz.yazproject.cek.services.CekService" url-pattern="/CekService"/>
</endpoints>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EftGidenServices</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EhacizServices</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CekService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EftGidenServices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/EftGidenServices</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EhacizServices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/EhacizServices</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CekService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CekService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: If I had to guess, it can't find one of the endpoint classes in your `sun-jaxws.xml` file. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571886/tomcat-failed-to-parse-runtime-descriptor